# can't access system after update (xorg/MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1)

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

On Ubuntu 12, I can't access system, it stays stuck on lightdm.

From tty, giving startx, I receive this message:

```
ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to server
X: Resource temporarily unavailable
xinit: server error
```

What can I do??

Thank you

Comment: Try the answers from this post on AU: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143179/startx-doesnt-work